# React web app routes not working with query string by using nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying to host my react website using nginx. everything works fine except the routes having query string.

```sh
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

```
http:// example.com                          //works fine
http:// example.com/courses                  //works fine
http:// example.com/courses?type=software    //not working shows blank page.
http:// example.com/courses?type=software&institute=xyz    //not working shows blank page.
```

Please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the query arguments:

```
try_files $uri /index.html$is_args$args;
```

Comment: Thank you @Tero Its working.